# How to access the case value withing the case expression in C/C++

Tags: c++, c

When you have some code like this

```
switch(some_value)
{
    case 1: call_template_function_x<1>();break;
    case 2: call_template_function_x<2>();break;
    case 3: call_template_function_x<3>();break;
    // etc
}
```

Here 'some_value' is known only at run-time and I'm using the switch to convert the run-time value to one of N functions which have a templated constant as input.

Is there any way I can replace the <1> in the templated function call with the value from the case statement, something like

```
case n: call_template_function_x<case_value_for_n>();break;
```

Comment: No. Leave the code as it is, which does exactly what it should.

Comment: The best you could do is a macro, or some complicated template metaprogramming but that will almost certainly be far less readable and well on the side of "too clever"

Comment: Um... Is there a reason `some_value` can't be a parameter to the function? How does the function depend on knowing it at compile time?

Comment: If you can convert the template functions into standalone functions with parameters, you could use a static lookup table or an std::map to call the appropriate function.  **See Dispatch pattern**

Answer (score 2):

No , there is no way to replace the values unless you write the case for all values from 0 to maximum of some value. This is because `call_template_function_x<3>()` is known at compile time and because of this the compiler knows what code to generate in the exe. Runtime values therefore will not be able to be used by the compiler to generate code.